# modal show not working after modal(hide) in jquery after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table in modal with edit button to update the user details

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">User Info</h4>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <form>
                    <div class="modal-body edit-info" >

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="roomupdate btn btn-warning">Save</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and my ajax code is

```
$(document).on('click', '.roomupdate', function(){
            ev.preventDefault();
            $id= $('#id').val();
            $building=$('#building').val();
            $floorno=$('#floorno').val();
            $roomno=$('#roomno').val();
            $priority=$('#priority1').val();
            $nobeds=$('#nobeds').val();
            $('#editModal').modal('hide');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "addroomlist.php",
                    async: false,
                    data: {
                        building: $building,
                        id: $id,
                        floorno: $floorno,
                        roomno: $roomno,
                        priority: $priority,
                        nobeds: $nobeds,
                        roomupdate: 1,
                    },
                    success: function(){
                        showUser();
                    },
                });
        });
```

and my edit button code to call modal with user info.

```
<td> <button data-id='<?php echo $row['id'] ?>' class='roomedit btn btn-warning'>Edit</button></td>
```

when i first click save button after modify the details its working fine and modal closed with
 `$('#editModal').Modal('hide');`
when i click edit button second time Modal not show up until i reload the page.
where it went wrong please help

Comment: Does any error getting shown in console? Also, how do you binding a click event to an "Edit" button? Please add that too in the question, it will help little more for giving an answer.

Comment: please share the code of `showuser()` function

Comment: Change `$(document).on('click', '.roomupdate', function(){` for `$('body').on('click', '.roomupdate', function(ev) {` and put `$('#editModal').modal('hide');` inside `success`, above `showUser();`

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax code remove `$('#editModal').modal('hide');` from the line where you are using right now and put it in success function of ajax.
Like:

```
success: function(){
$('#editModal').modal('hide');
showUser();},
```

and if you are using `location.reload();` in your `showUser();` function then it will work but as far i know i think you did not add it in `showUser();` so add also `location.reload();` after `showUser();` function or at the end of code written in `showUser();` function.

And one more thing do you write any code by which clicking on edit button the modal should open in javascript?

Comment: No, opening Modal when click edit button done with bootstrap only

Comment: my showUser() code    `function showUser(){
        $uid=$('#linkid').val();
  $.ajax({
   url: 'addroomlist.php',
   type: 'POST',
   async: false,
   data:{
                uid:$uid,
    buildingshow: 1,
   },
   success: function(response){
    $('#buildingtable').html(response);
   },
  });
 }`

Comment: Well, according to your showUser() function, you have to add `location.reload();` after your showUser() function. like
`success: function(){
$('#editModal').modal('hide');
showUser();
location.reload();},`

Also show modal using javascript like
`$(document).on('click','.your-button',function () {
$("#editModal").modal('show');
});`

Here .your-button is the class of that button, whose click show you edit modal.